# HTML/CSS: Create a div that always fills the entire page... and then a resizeable div within it?

Tags: html, css, resize

I feel like this is an easy question, but for whatever reason I can't figure it out today.

I need a div that always fills the entire page, no matter how large that page is. Then I need another div which I can re-size with javascript (mydiv.style.width = x; mydiv.style.height = y;).

If the second div is resized to be taller than the existing browser window height, the first div should resize to fit.

i.e. If the first div's background color is red, I should *never* see any white background color, because the first div always expands to the size of the entire page.

I tried this, it doesn't work because the red background doesn't expand to the size of the entire page:

[example of the problem](http://www.academickeys.com/tmp/test.html)

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? Putting the `scroll_layer` inside `flashlayer` will make the `flashlayer` to expand with it, as long as the `scroll_layer` div is in the flow (eg. not floated and statically/relatively positioned)

Answer (score 2):

I think Zack's alternate is the best answer: the `body` element IS a block-level element that always fills the entire 'page'. You can hook into it with JavaScript and CSS, just as you can with a div. Color your `body` element red and you'll never see white if your inner div is resized. If you don't want your CSS applied to every page in your site, add a class or ID to the body of the page you want to affect, and write your CSS to select only body elements with a specific class or ID.

Am I missing a requirement that's not addressed by using the `body` element?

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting blasted by the CSS purists for this, but I recently solved this problem by using a table.

You need an outer div, set to "position:relative" and 100% height, and then you put a table inside, also 100% each way.

More explanation here: http://wondersofcomputing.blogspot.com/2009/07/table-height-browser-window-height.html

You're welcome to spurn the table solution. But then I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this?

```
if (wholePageDiv.style.height < myDiv.style.height) {
    wholePageDiv.style.height = myDiv.style.height + 10
}
```

An alternative -- if that background div only needs to be a color -- is to just set the body's background-color to whatever you need. Then you don't need to worry about any javascript resizing of the background.

Comment: This wouldn't work unless I also modify the whole page div with javascript when the page is first loaded, and then every time the other thing changes size... that's kinda nasty, I'd rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Holy crap ive solved it, a FULLY CENTERED DIV, enjoy.

EDIT: minor cosmetic fix

---

Index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>

<style>
body {text-align: center;}
p {width: 300px;}
.greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;}
.wrapperA { display: table; width: 1px; height: 1px; margin: 0 auto;}
.wrapperB { display: table-cell; #position: absolute; #top: 50%; vertical-align: middle;}
.wrapperC { #position: relative; #top: -50%;}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function resize(id) {
var block = document.getElementById(id);
var htmlheight = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
if (htmlheight > window.innerHeight) {htmlheight = window.innerHeight;}
block.style.height = htmlheight + "px";}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="resize('wrapper')" onresize="resize('wrapper')">
<div class="wrapperA greenBorder" id="wrapper">
<div class="wrapperB greenBorder">
<div class="wrapperC greenBorder">

<p>CENTERED CONTENT</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE6 goes into infinite loop and browser freeze with that resize code.

Comment: The question didn't say needs to be IE6 compatible, and i personally think coders should start to force people to update by only coding to standards, it would make like that much easier.
But hey that's just my excuse for not knowing how to do it in IE6.
For everyone else, it works.