# Vertical align a block

Tags: css, xhtml

How on earth do you center a div vertically?

Horizontal has enough ways already, but no matter what i try, vertical centering is just impossible.

> body { vertical-align: middle;}

Does nothing

> body {text-align: middle;}

Does nothing

> div.middle {top: 50%;}

Does nothing

Is it even possible?

I think i'm gonna cry.

Comment: heres the final result - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890944/html-css-create-a-div-that-always-fills-the-entire-page-and-then-a-resizeable/1900027#1900027

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
> <html>
> <head>
>   <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
>   <style>
>     .greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;} /* just borders to ser it */
>   </style>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>   <div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
>     <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
>       <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
>         any text<br>
>         any height<br>
>         any content, for example generated from DB<br>
>         everything is vertically centered
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: thanks, nice code but, there's that damn 'set height' limit again, so i guess there's no way to center a block for use with different screen res?

Comment: You can make the outer div 100% height. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238/100-min-height-css-layout

Answer (score 1):

use [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for doing that. Here is the link to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/rohitbind/pen/jAzXdA). This is **simple and best solution** what i feel. If you are not taking care of the IE Browsers then this is the best method of aligning the Blocks. "Angular Material" is also using this to make its grid.

```
<div class="center">
      <div>
            <h4>
                  I am at center
            </h4>
      </div>
</div>


.center {
      /*this is for styling */
      height: 100px;
      margin: 1em;
      color:#fff;
      background: #9f5bd0;

      /*you just have to use this */
      display: flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
}
```

**To learn 'Flexible Box Layout Module' you can visit FLEXBOX FROGGY.**

Answer (score 0):

The div has to have a fixed height in order to make it possible, as far as I know.

```
#centered { width: 700px; height: 400px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -200px 0 0 -350px; }
```

And make the parent layer of `#centered` relatively positioned. That should work.

Edit - So it is possible to have an undefined height. See cletus' answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your outer div is "position: relative" OR "position: absolute" (for a point of reference).  2. Set a fixed height for the inner div. 3. Set the inner div to "top: 50%" to move it down to the middle. 4. And the step people forget is to set "margin-top: -yy" (-yy is half the height of the inner div to offset the div upwards).

Say your inner div was set to height: 100px;.  The code would be:

```
<style type="text/css">
#outerDiv { position: relative }
#innerDiv { position: absolute; top: 50%; height: 100px; margin-top: -50px }
</style>
```